# Автоматическое обновление корпоративного ПО под Windows

Tags: windows, развертывание

Занимаюсь разработкой корпоративных приложений под .NET для внутреннего использования под Windows. Столкнулся с проблемой распространения как самих приложений, так и обновлений к ним.

Видел, что многие фирмы (тот же Adobe или Apple) делают свои сервисы для распространиения своих программ. Неужели нет какого-нибудь готового инструмента? Вроде Linux-ового менеджера пакетов.

Answer (score 2):

Можно делать установщик MSI и распространять его через групповые политики домена.

Но в целом так и есть: нет никакого общего механизма для обновлений.

Comment: "нет никакого общего механизма для обновлений." A WSUS и SCCM ?

Comment: @Евгений это только для программ Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

https://chocolatey.org/ - есть вот такой проект. Он даже на [тэчнете](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn927162.aspx) Майкрософта упоминается. [Статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/143996/).

В отличии от GPO - этот способ в качестве транспорта передачи использует *http*.

Comment: А есть возможность (и насколько это сложно?) использовать свой сервер для раздачи пакетов?

Comment: Да, возможно, потому что код лежит на гитхабе - соотетственно палки в колёса вида "качайте только с нашего аппстора" вставлять не будет. Например вот: https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/How-To-Change-Cache https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/ChocolateyFAQs https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CreatePackagesQuickStart